# Android Volley com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake failed

Tags: php, android, ssl

Ok so this is my third time asking for the same program, i'm really sorry for this because i don't know how to connect android app to phpmyadmin. So, i got this  SSL handshake failed problem and i don't know if it is because it isn't verified or if i even have one installed.

Here's my android code:

```
Android Studio MainActvity code
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText UserRegName, UserRegContact, UserRegEmail, UserRegPass;
private Button btUserReg;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    UserRegName = findViewById(R.id.UserRegName);
    UserRegContact = findViewById(R.id.UserRegContact);
    UserRegEmail = findViewById(R.id.UserRegEmail);
    UserRegPass = findViewById(R.id.UserRegPass);

    btUserReg = findViewById(R.id.btnUserRegister);
    btUserReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Regist();
}
});

}
private void Regist(){
    btUserReg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    final String UserRegName =this.UserRegName.getText().toString().trim();
    final String UserRegContact =this.UserRegContact.getText().toString().trim();
    final String UserRegEmail =this.UserRegEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String UserRegPass =this.UserRegPass.getText().toString().trim();



    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, " http://192.168.254.113/UserRegistration/register.php "  ,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            String success = jsonObject.getString(" success");
            if(success.equals(" 1")){
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Register Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException en) {
            en.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Register Failed!"+ en.toString(), 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       btUserReg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
                }
            },
    new Response.ErrorListener(){

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Register Error!"+ error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("UserRegName",UserRegName);
            params.put("  UserRegContact ", UserRegContact);
            params.put("UserRegEmail",UserRegEmail);
            params.put("UserRegPass",UserRegPass);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
}
```

Also, here is my php code which contains the register program

```
<?php


$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$ContactNo = $_POST['ContactNo'];
$Pass = $_POST['Password'];

$Sql_Query = "insert into data (Name,Email,ContactNo,Password) values 
('$Name','$Email','$ContactNo',$Pass)";

if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query)){

echo 'Data Inserted Successfully';

}
else{

echo 'Try Again';

}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Did you added this line in `manifest`?

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: I already put it in manifest file

Comment: so, same error showing?

Comment: Are you using a self-signed certificate on your server?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score -1):

Check if

1. You have proper internet
2. Added internet permission on manifest
3. If your website doesn't have https, you have to provide non https version (aka http) of the URL and enable cleartext traffic on manifest

Comment: 1 and 2 are far too vague for answers, 3 doesnt seem relevant as the url is `http://192.168.254.113`

Comment: 1. I don't know how to react to this
2. I already have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" in my manifest
3. I'm not sure about this, but I changed my URL in android studio from http to https because of a certian problem. That's probably the cause since i'm not sure if I already use SSL in my server.

Comment: @WesleySmith no, these are not vague. those have happened to me before.

Comment: "proper internet" and "internet permission" are indeed quite vague. Though they may relate in some way to issues youve had before, neither of those points as laid out would be helpful to someone having these problems. This tells the OP nothing of what these things mean, how to check them, and gives no indication of how they could be fixed if they are wrong.

Comment: @WesleySmith Context is the key here. If it were a facebook post, It would have been vague. But OP is asking about network related issues. So, proper internet means, he can connect to other servers except for this. And Someone working on android "internet permission on manifest" is as clear as the sky on a sunny day